# boilerplate cordova app fails on windows after adding angular reference

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova

I've created a new cordova project via the following steps in the cmd window (directly from the [cordova Windows Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%20Platform%20Guide)):

```
> cordova create wintest com.mystuff.test "Windows Test"
> cd wintest
> cordova platform add windows
> cordova build windows
> cordova run windows --device -- --phone
```

At this point the app works in the emulator, and I get the screen with the cordova icon with "Device is Ready" blinking.  All is glorious.

Next I insert (immediately before the reference to cordova.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
```

Then I build & run the emulator again and the app launches then immediately closes.

```
> cordova build windows
> cordova run windows --device -- --phone
```

Any ideas (in case it matters, I'm developing on a win10 machine)?

**Edit/Update**: Running "cordova serve" and testing in both Edge & Chrome throws the following exception (even after removing angular.js, so apparently that was a red herring)

> "Refused to load the script 'http://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

**Update 2**: Even after updating Content-Security-Policy to allow "script-src *", it still can't find the microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js file it's looking for.  I'm assuming this has something to do with it but don't know for sure.

Comment: check on the browser what is causing the issue using: 
> cordova serve

Comment: Thanks.  This revealed it looks like a Content Security Policy issue (I've included more detail in the original post).  I'll dig into this further and will post back if I solve it.

Comment: what if you include the url from that library on the script-src, like: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/*